# Calculated query string is not working properly (php)

Tags: php, web-services, curl, file-get-contents

Have to invoke a GET-WS from `php`.
Url : `https://testWS/CompanyGeneralInformation?IdUser=123&CUI=345`

When query-string is added static it working properly.
`$out = file_get_contents("https://testWS/CompanyGeneralInformation?CUI=345&IdUser=123")`

But when is calculated in advance and passed as parameter, got error

```
$id=123;
$qs="https://testWS/CompanyGeneralInformation?CUI=345&IdUser=".$id;
$out = file_get_contents($qs);
//but this is OK
//$qs="https://testWS/CompanyGeneralInformation?CUI=345&IdUser=123";
//$out = file_get_contents($qs);
```

Error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://...CompanyGeneralInformation?IdUser=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<int xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">123</int>&CUI=567)
: Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400
```

Note: Seem id is translated to XML from server-side ???
Further more get the same issues with custom parameter with POST(via curl), when static always work

Post via curl (error)

```
$str=strval("CUI=".$cui."&IdUser=".$id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"$str"); //or either $str 

System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.
Form value was detected from the client (IdUser="<?xml version="1.0" ..."). 
at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, 
RequestValidationSource requestCollection) at 
System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, 
RequestValidationSource requestCollection) at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() at 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.HtmlFormParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request) at 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters() at 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

Note: WS doc specify:
 `GET /link/CompanyGeneralInformation?CUI=string&IdUser=string HTTP/1.1`

Response is xml (but irrelevant now).

Note(error source): `Response is xml (but irrelevant now)` : very relevant since got the error after using WS to get id in first place and not transformed into a variable. Then id was passed (actually xml since not parsed).

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
...
```

Kindly let me know what could be the issue.

Comment: If you are having the same problem in CURL and file_get_contents, there is something else happening. What shows when you do something like **echo "<xmp>$id</xmp>";**?? or **echo strlen($id);**

Comment: If that is what shows when echoing $id, then you aren't passing it a simple number like in your example.

Comment: That means you aren't actually getting the id from the XML, I would look at the code that extracts the ID from the XML since that is where the problem is at.

Comment: @imvain2. Yes, got the entire xml and passed as id. Should pay more attention. Kindly post to accept answer. Working properly after got the id from xml. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments of your echoing and the error mentioned, it does seem like this is simply an issue with not extracting the needed information from your XML before passing it via URL.